postgres: Connection already closed issue
I'm encountering a "connection already closed" error in my Django application that uses PostgreSQL as the database backend. Despite trying various solutions, I can't seem to resolve this issue.
Background Information:

Django 4.2.13
psycopg2 2.9.9

Problem Statement
I have a Django application that intermittently throws a "connection already closed" error when trying to interact with the PostgreSQL database. This issue often arises under the following circumstances:
Running background task for inserting data into db in every 30 seconds
errors:                                                                                           File "django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in innerreturn func(*args, **kwargs)
File "django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 330, in cursorreturn self._cursor()
File "django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 308, in _cursorreturn self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
File "django\db\utils.py", line 91, in exitraise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 308, in _cursorreturn self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
File "django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in innerreturn func(*args, **kwargs)
File "django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 330, in create_cursorcursor =   
self.connection.cursor()django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed

What I’ve Tried

Ensured that the database connection parameters are correct.
Checked for any long-running queries that might be causing timeouts.
Adjusted Django's database connection settings such as CONN_MAX_AGE and CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS.
Increased the connection timeout settings in PostgreSQL.

Despite these attempts, the issue persists.

CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS only works in a (HTTP) request context. It doesn't do anything when used in a background task:

If set to True, existing persistent database connections will be health checked before they are reused in each request performing database access.

This is a known issue.
You should be doing a similar check manually in your loop. We don't see your actual code, but it will be something similar to the following:
from django.db import close_old_connections

while True:
    close_old_connections()
    # ...do the things ...
    time.sleep(30) 

